# How to create a see-through Rectangle in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I want to make an Image 100% transparent through a small rectangle and 50% transparent from all others. As if making a small hole to see-through the small rectangle. Here is my code...

```
struct ImageScope: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("test_pic")

            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.5))

            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 150)
                .foregroundColor(Color.orange.opacity(0.0))
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3).stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 3))
        }
    }
}
```

For easier understanding...

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is working approach. It is used custom shape and even-odd fill style.

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

Below demo with more transparency contrast for better visibility.

[image: demo]

```
struct Window: Shape {
    let size: CGSize
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Rectangle().path(in: rect)

        let origin = CGPoint(x: rect.midX - size.width / 2, y: rect.midY - size.height / 2)
        path.addRect(CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))
        return path
    }
}

struct ImageScope: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("test_pic")

            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
                .mask(Window(size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 150)).fill(style: FillStyle(eoFill: true)))

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3).stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 3)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 150)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `blendMode(.destinationOut)` you don't have to draw custom shape and it is only one line of code. Sometimes adding `.compositingGroup()` modifier is neccessary.

```swift
ZStack {
    Color.black.opacity(0.5)
    Rectangle()
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        .blendMode(.destinationOut) // << here
}
.compositingGroup()
```

Comment: I tried this and a few variations but couldn't get it to work. I think this answer needs a little more explanation and/or code(with use of Image).

Comment: @Marcy Please, try adding the `.compositingGroup()` modifier on the `ZStack`.

Answer (score 4):

For clarity, this solution is based on eja08's answer but fully flushed out using an image. The blend mode .destinationOut creates the cutout in the black rectangle. The nested ZStack places the image in the background without being impacted by the blend mode.

```
struct ImageScope: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("test_pic")
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.black.opacity(0.5))
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 150)
                    .blendMode(.destinationOut)
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3).stroke(.white, lineWidth: 3))
            }
            .compositingGroup()
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

[image]